# From which Dockerfile should composer install be called from

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to call `composer install` and unsure from which Dockerfile to call it from - `Dockerfile-apache` or `Dockerfile-php-fpm`?

Should I install composer in `Dockerfile-apache` (and PHP CLI?) and run it from there?

Running composer install from Dockerfile-php-fpm gives me this: `Composer could not find a composer.json file in /var/www/html`

`Docker-php-fpm`

```
# Do we target a specific version? ie. 7.4.25?
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Need to add zip and other extensions
RUN buildDeps=" \
        libonig-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        libxml2-dev \ 
    " \ 
&& apt-get -y update \
&& apt-get install -y $buildDeps zip libicu-dev \ 
&& docker-php-ext-configure intl \
&& docker-php-ext-install intl mbstring json mysqli opcache pdo pdo_mysql xml \ 
&& apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
&& rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copying of base conf files
COPY docker/php-fpm/conf/php-fpm.conf /usr/local/etc
COPY docker/php-fpm/conf/php.ini-development /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY docker/php-fpm/conf/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d

# Install Composer.
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php \
        && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/ \
        && ln -s /usr/local/bin/composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

EXPOSE 9000
```

`Docker-apache`:

```
FROM httpd:2.4

# Copy config files
COPY docker/apache/conf/httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf
COPY docker/apache/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/extra

# Do something about log rotate?

# Create vhost directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html

#Set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

#copy files
COPY bin ${APP_HOME}/bin
COPY config ${APP_HOME}/config
COPY plugins ${APP_HOME}/plugins
COPY src ${APP_HOME}/src
COPY webroot ${APP_HOME}/webroot
COPY .htaccess ${APP_HOME}
COPY index.php ${APP_HOME}
COPY composer.json ${APP_HOME}
COPY composer.lock ${APP_HOME}
```

**Edit #1**

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: php-fpm
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php-fpm
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  apache:
    container_name: httpd
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-apache
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
```

Edit #2

This docker-compose file enables the communication via a common volume. I just need to compile, build and copy the files in Apache at this point.

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  php-fpm:
    container_name: php-fpm
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-php-fpm
    volumes:
      - mydata:/var/www/html:rw
    networks:
      - backend
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  apache:
    container_name: httpd
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-apache
    depends_on:
      - php
    volumes:
      - mydata:/var/www/html:rw
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
networks:
  frontend:
  backend:
volumes:
  mydata:
```

Comment: Why do you want to install PHP in an Apache container? Why not use the PHP container for that? Why not use Composer in a seperate container?

Comment: From the PHP container, it doesn't find the required json file, assuming it's due to the Apache container being created after? Would I need to do the Apache container first? Added my docker-compose.yml.

Comment: I think I need to mount a volume from the Apache image and make it available to the PHP image using volume-from?

Comment: "From the PHP container, it doesn't find the required json file" - what does that mean? Your PHP container does not contain any files. Why did you copy them into the Apache container?

Comment: @nicohaase I figured that's where they went. Currently browser both containers, the Apache one has files, the PHP doesn't. If I were to put the files into the PHP one, wouldn't I get 404 since the Apache one is empty? I think I'm missing volumes to enable access to/from containers.

Comment: @nicohasse I figured out how to communicate between the containers. I'll probably follow the advice in the answer below, compile and get everything and copy into Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with neither of the above; instead, **run `composer install` locally and copy the resulting `vendor` directory as part of your application**.

Fetching dependencies is fundamentally part of *building* an application, not part of *running* it, so Composer shouldn't even be installed on a production host or container. If you were writing a C application which needed to be compiled with `gcc`, you would run that as an earlier step, and then copy the binary into the container; `composer install` can be treated the same way.

So for instance, you might have a build script (to run manually, or in a CI server like Jenkins, Github Actions, Azure DevOps, etc) that went through the following steps:

1. Clone the repo from a git repository
2. Check out the latest tag
3. Run `composer install`
4. Run a script to minify the client-side JS
5. Run `docker-composer`, copying the source code, minified JS, and `vendor` directory

The software *inside* the Docker container therefore only needs to be able to *run* the application, not *build* it.

Comment: Can you elaborate where "locally" would be? Would it be in a step before running docker-compose?

Comment: @TechFanDan See edit.